# Torus biholomorphic to smooth cubic curve?

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry

I am trying to understand that all compact genus 1 Riemann surfaces are biholomorphic to a smooth cubic curve. ( assuming that $\dim H^{1,0} = \dim H^{0,1} = \frac{1}{2} \dim H^1$ )

I think I understand how it can be shown that they are all biholomorphic to a torus $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ for some lattice $\Lambda$, but I am stuck to show it for the curve.

I would really appreciate a hint. Am I missing something that makes it obvious that the smooth cubic curve would be biholomorphic to the torus ?

Comment: This is really a problem that one resolves in the study of elliptic curves. Namely, the fact that their is a bijection between the biholomorphism classes of elliptic curves (which are smooth cubics) and tori. There are many references for the proof of this. For example, see here: http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/toriec.pdf